# The sequence of calling functions in laravel route?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Example below:

```
Route::get('users/{id}', function ($id) {
    //code
})->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

The anonymous function will be called first or "where" function will be called first?

In my opinion, I think the anonymous function will be called first. But I think this is not reasonable, I think it is reasonable that only the id meet the regular expressions can call the anonymous function.

So what sequence is it exactly?

Comment: @SariYono what are you talking about? He's talking about routes, not eloquent.

Comment: my bad i guess it was too late in the evening.

Answer (score 0):

The `where` will be ran first.

Why?

the `get` function returns an `object` as well as the `where`. So if Laravel calls upon that **Route**, the Route object will be built first before firing the Route's actions.

```
$obj = Route::get() // returns an object, meaning that object returned has a function `where`.

$obj->where() // still returns the same object but validated.
```

So you have an object after the `where` call. That's what Laravel will use to perform an action on that route.

Like: `performRoute($obj) // this is only for example`

You can review the Route functions here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bd352a0d2ca93775fce8ef02365b03fc4fb8cbb0/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php